# JQuery plugins will not load

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

I have created a simple jquery example. On loading, the script should cause h1 tag to disappear from view, this however, is not happening.

I believe I have placed the scripts in the correct location, and in the right order. Please see below for markup and script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1> JS</h1>

    <div id="top">
        <h1> JS</h1>
    </div>

    <section id="grid"> 
        <table
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">About</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">Machinery</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">Gallery</a></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </section>

</body>
```

```
${document}.ready(function() {

$("h1").hide();

$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");

    alert("you clicked!");
});
```

});

Comment: press F12 and read the console. Also suggest using a code editor that has at least some basic syntax highlighting/checking. You have a typo on line 1.

Comment: thank you. Any editor you recommend. Using sublime.

Comment: sublime should be able to do it, i don't use it anymore, but pretty sure it had plugins that do linting for you. Look for eslint

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a couple of typos.  Instead of curly brackets, document ready should be used like this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready();
```

Also in your html you are not closing your opening `<table>` tag.